# Jquery changing class and trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <span class="fake_h">Too</span>
</body>

<script>
  $('.fake_h').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active_h').removeClass('fake_h');
  })
  $('.active_h').click(function() {
    alert()
  })
</script>
```

When I click on span it removes the class `fake_h` and add `active_h`. But after that when I click `span(class='active_h')` It doesn't work. Don't trigger alert or anything. Can anyone explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: `$(body).on("click", '.active_h', function(){  alert(123) })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `span` with some `div` and use that div `class` to trigger your dynamic added `class`. Changing the identifiers dynamically need to use delegated event handlers.

```js
$('.yourClass').on("click", '.fake_h', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active_h').removeClass('fake_h');
})
$('.yourClass').on("click", '.active_h', function() {
  alert()
})
```

```css
.active_h {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='yourClass'>
  <span class="fake_h">Too</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fake_h').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('active_h');
       $(this).removeClass('fake_h');
    });

    $('body').on("click", '.active_h', function(){ 
       alert('active_h'); 
    });
});
```